# Compiling LESS throws error

Tags: php, css, less

I am a beginner in LESS. I have a less file and I am passing variables [using PHP to LESS](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php) file for its compilation.Less file contains a lot more variables and the values for variable each time I pass via PHP differs. Sometimes I may not need some variables to be passed. If I left it, then error is thrown like

```
variable @size is undefined: failed at `font-size: @size; `webforms.less on line 52
```

Is this neccessary to pass values for all the variables provided in LESS file. If so, how can we overcome this?

Comment: What you mean by "not need some variables"? If it's used in LESS file, that means, you need it.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @dragoste Is there any option in less not to use some variables specified in it. Because if less file contains 50 variables, I need only 30/40 at a time. How can we achieve it. Also we cannot confirm what variable can be passed every time...

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to pass all the variables in your LESS file. Otherwise it will not compile into generic CSS file/form. In your case, I hope, you can try to set some default values inside your php script and then just pass them as array in ->setVariables method.

Answer (score 0):

You should define all your variables with a default value and only reassign those you want to change. 
Less uses **last declaration wins** for variables, so your can assign your changed variables at the end of your code.

Example:

```
@color: red;
p {
color: @color;
}
@color: green;
```

outputs:

```
p {
  color: green;
}
```

Also check the `modify-var` option of the compiler:

> --modify-var='VAR=VALUE' Modifies a variable already declared in the
>   file.